# Java XML Service with Template Model Class

Tags: java, xml, rest

I am trying to implement a Web Service with Java which produces list of class elements as XML.

As a basic approach my `FinalModel` class is:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "report")
public class FinalModel {
List<ReturnModel> returnList;

public FinalModel() { }

public FinalModel(List<ReturnModel> returnList){
    this.returnList = returnList;
}

public List<ReturnModel> getReturnList() {
    return returnList;
}

public void setReturnList(List<ReturnModel> returnList) {
    this.returnList = returnList;
}
}
```

and my `ReturnModel` is a basic Java class which implements `Comparable`.

And in my `Service` class, I can produce the XML like that:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/{opt}")
public FinalModel generate(@PathParam("opt") String opt) {

    try {

        System.out.println("[SERVICE] [INFO] Connected...");

        Main m = new Main();
        FinalModel returnModel = m.init();
            
        if(returnModel == null){
            System.out.println("[SERVICE] [INFO] Someting went wrong.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("[SERVICE] [INFO] Completed successfully.");
        }
        
        return returnModel;
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("[SERVICE] [ERROR] Exception: " + e.getMessage() + "\n\t\t" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return new FinalModel();
    }
}
```

Where the `m.init()` returns a `FinalModel` object which contains a list of `ReturnModel`. And there is no problem with this way.

However, when I tried to make `FinalModel` as template class, it fails and the service got 500 Internal Error.

`FinalModel`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "report")
public class FinalModel<T> {
List<T> returnList;

public FinalModel() { }

public FinalModel(List<T> returnList){
    this.returnList = returnList;
}

public List<T> getReturnList() {
    return returnList;
}

public void setReturnList(List<T> returnList) {
    this.returnList = returnList;
}
}
```

and my `ReturnModel` class is same.

And in my `Service` class, I produce the XML like that:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/{opt}")
public FinalModel<ReturnModel> generate(@PathParam("opt") String opt) {

    try {

        System.out.println("[SERVICE] [INFO] Connected...");

        Main m = new Main();
        FinalModel<ReturnModel> returnModel = m.init();
            
        if(returnModel == null){
            System.out.println("[SERVICE] [INFO] Someting went wrong.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("[SERVICE] [INFO] Completed successfully.");
        }
        
        return returnModel;
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("[SERVICE] [ERROR] Exception: " + e.getMessage() + "\n\t\t" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return new FinalModel<ReturnModel>();
    }
}
```

Where the `m.init()` returns a `FinalModel<ReturnModel>` object.

And when I changed my code like that, it fails.

So, what is wrong? Why the template class is not working and how should I do?

=========================

[EDIT]

The m.init() is like that:

```
public FinalModel<ReturnModel> init() {
    
    try {

        ArrayList<ReturnModel> results = new ArrayList<>();

        ReturnModel rm = new ReturnModel(name, surname, gender, address);
        
        results.add(rm);

        
        return new FinalModel<ReturnModel>(results);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: It will be helpful to post the stack trace of the error causing error 500

Comment: Also, you need to add your `Main.init()` method

Comment: @PiagetHadzizi I added the m.init(). There is no stack trace just a regular 500 html message return from Postman. And there is no error in my Tomcat.

Comment: And of course the name, surname etc are placeholders. They are defined in my code :)

Comment: You are very close to fixing this issue. Create an ideal request body and send it to the server that is giving you 500. Just to see if it accepts anything. When you get the correct body format, compare it with what you are sending

Comment: The service gets the request, called the init and the init gets the data very well. So, the body is correct actually :) The problem is on the service's return. It is not understanding the Template, i believe.

Comment: If you debug your generate() method when you process a request, how far does it go before something fails? Does it reach a return statement?

Comment: Hey @DarkMatter, it reaches the return statement in try. Then it can't respond back to the client.